# return the results of sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, devops, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to write a pipeline as a code and in this pipeline I want to return the result of sonarqube analyze and do a filter if the general note is >=97 continue if it is less return a Notif in slack.
but how can I return a result a of sonarqube

Comment: Just to clarify do you mean to read the result been published to sonarcube for a particular project before and after ?

Comment: yes  but after .I want to retrieve the general note of an analysis to make a filter on the note  exemple : (if "note"> 95 ... else ....) . i want to integrate  the if bloc in jenkins pipeline

Answer (score 4):

There are so called **[quality gates](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates)** in Sonarqube which can be configured to fail the build if necessary.

You will have to configure a **webhook** between Sonarqube and Jenkins so that you pipeline can ask for the quality gate status.
Further information can be found here: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sonar/

Note: Especially have a look at the method **waitForQualityGate()** which does exactly what you intend to do!